# Create new child formGroup into formGroup - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an angular 6 app. And I have a form like below stackblitz.

[PERFECTLY WORKING SAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqwos5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

But, I want create a shared `country-state` component. And I want to call when I need. So, I convert my project into below stackblitz. **But, I don't want create new form group for `country-state`. I want to use from parent** . But, I can't execute my second stackblitz.

[NOT WORKING SAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcqig4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why you do not pass the FormGroup as an Input to the child component ?

Comment: I'm new at angular. How can I do that? @selemmn

Comment: It's quite contradictory to extract the country and the state to a separate component, but to force each user of that component to create the form controls for that separate component instead of letting it create its own form controls. Why don't you want to create a separate form group?

Comment: Because I'm using a lot of page @JBNizet. And I don't want write everywhere same code.

Comment: That's precisely why you should not force every usage of the separate component to create the controls, and instead let the separate component do it. So why don't you want to create a separate form group for this separate component?

Comment: Because there will be two recursive formgroup. And getting and managing values is more difficult. So, I prefered this way @JBNizet

Comment: that could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334283/reactive-forms-how-to-add-new-formgroup-or-formarray-into-an-existing-formgroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a main purpose of `@Input()` decorator in angular:

In your `country-state.component.ts`  add `Input` to your import and use that decorator as mentioned below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-country-state',
  templateUrl: './country-state.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./country-state.component.css']
})
export class CountryStateComponent implements OnInit {

  countries: Country[];
  states: State[];

  @Input() 
  studentForm; // <-- This
...
}
```

Then in your app.component.ts change your child tag to:

```
<app-country-state [studentForm]="studentForm"></app-country-state>
```

After that and in your `country-state.component.html` add `form` tag like :

```
<form [formGroup]="studentForm">
    <label>Country:</label> 
    <select formControlName="countryId" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
      <option [value]="0">--Select--</option>
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>State:</label>
    <select formControlName="stateId">
      <option [value]="0">--Select--</option>
      <option *ngFor="let state of states " value= {{state.id}}>{{state.name}}</option>
    </select>
 </form>
```

Thus, you wont create a new `formgroup` instance but you'll be using the parent's one.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir, could you tell me please why did you accept the other answer ? it was a bit copy/paste from mine ?

Comment: Sory. I saw that working in stackblitz. So, I marked. But, you are right. I'm changing immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Try composite form using controlContainer

**parent.component.ts**

```
this.studentForm = new FormGroup({
      'studentName': new FormControl(''),
      'stateId': new FormControl(''),
      'countryId': new FormControl('')
    })
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="studentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>Student Name:</label> 
    <input formControlName="studentName">
    <br/><br/>
    <app-country-state></app-country-state>
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Inside child component provide ViewContainer to get parent group control

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Country } from '../country';
import { State } from '../state';
import { SelectService } from '../select.service';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, FormGroup, ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-country-state',
  templateUrl: './country-state.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./country-state.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class CountryStateComponent implements OnInit {
  countryId;

  countryState: FormGroup;
  countries: Country[];
  states: State[];

  constructor(private selectService: SelectService, private parentcontrol: FormGroupDirective) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.countryState = this.parentcontrol.control;

    this.parentcontrol.control.updateValueAndValidity();
    //  this.parentcontrol.control.addControl('stateId', new FormControl(''));
    this.countries = this.selectService.getCountries();
  }


  onSelect(countryid) {
    // this.states = this.selectService.getStates().filter((item) => item.countryid == this.studentForm.controls.countryId.value);
  }

}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guqxbh

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Chellappan

Comment: But your stackblitz example not working. Please can you edit it @Chellappan .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited `onChange` event. People who need full working version access from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfoiav?file=src/app/country-state/country-state.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass your formGroup to child component as an input

country-state.component.ts

```
@Input() studentForm;
```

in app.component.html

```
<app-country-state [studentForm]="studentForm"></app-country-state>
```

in country-state.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="studentForm" >
   ....
  </form>
```

I have modified your code 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3pqgk

Comment: Thanks a lot @Indrakumara. This is what I was looking for.